# NSNotificationCenter addObserver being ignored

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, nsnotificationcenter, addobserver

Two objects were working just fine receiving `NSNotifications` before with XCode 5.1 (and CorePlot 1.4).  However, with XCode 5.1.1 (Coreplot 1.5) I found that if the `addObserver` call is inside the `init` method, it won't actually be registered (just for those two classes, it works in the parent object of a different class).  I even put a `NSLog` before and after the call to make sure the code was still working.  The objects are both strongly referenced by their shared parent, and their parent receives the necessary notifications without issue.  And, I have a `NSLog` in the `dealloc` where the `removeObserver` is -it is not called early, as the objects are retained properly.

```
//The object is a CorePlot CPTGraphHostingView
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        //other code setting up a few private ivar primitive arrays and values

        //this is where the call was (there are actually 3 Observer calls made)
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        addObserver: self
        selector: @selector(recordUpdated)
        name: @"recordUpdated"
        object: nil];

        //then this is called before the end
        [self prepareGraph];

        //this is where I moved it
        [self startListening];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Again, nothing has changed about the code for the object sending the notification or those two classes since I last compiled it with XCode 5.1 (and CorePlot 1.4).  And this same call is used in the `init` of the parent, and works perfectly.  My only solution last night was to refactor out the `addObserver` calls into a new method, and call that method at the end of `init`.

However, I don't understand why this was necessary.  Can anyone think of a reason that `addObserver` placed in the middle of `init` would be "ignored", but when inside another method called by `init`, it works?

**Edit, and notes:**

I added more code to show the init.  I also added notes that it is a graph view for CorePlot, and the CorePlot was also recently updated to 1.5 (I forgot about that) -which could be the source of the problem.

lead_the_zeppelin's suggestion that it is being reassigned, seems possible.  But wouldn't the call from NSNotificationCenter to a -now- dealloc'd object crash the program (note, dealloc is NOT called - I have a `NSLog` there)?  I could easily test this by printing the object instance string inside the `init`, and afterwards.  I did test this last night, asking for the instance, but I don't think I copied that bit into the `init`.

Comment: It seems like this must have something to do with the other things happening in your init method. Perhaps posting that would allow us to help?

Comment: Done.  Doing so made me realize that I also updated CorePlot recently as well.

Comment: Just to check, you've got a `NSLog` (or a breakpoint) in the `recordUpdated` method yeah to check its being called? (I know it sounds obvious, but its so easily done!)

Comment: Also can you post the code which send a notification please :)

Comment: Are you using ARC? You might try running with NSZombies enabled to see if there's an early dealloc happening.

Comment: @Jesse, Yes, I am using ARC.  Dealloc is not being called, as I have a `NSLog` inside the dealloc method, which would warn me - and I can still talk to the object just fine.

Comment: @Rich, yes there is a NSLog inside the `recordUpdated` method.  Actually, it's even more obvious, when it is called the graph on the screen updates. So if it isn't called, nothing happens on the screen.

Comment: Is it possible that prepareGraph is calling `removeObserver:self`? Maybe something it calls?

Comment: @JesseRusak, `prepareGraph` is a method I wrote.  Eric did find the cause in the super class, now I need to find a reliable way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Core Plot hosting view removes itself as an observer of all notifications whenever you set the hosted graph or the `collapsesLayers` property. Please post a bug report on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues) if you'd like us to fix it.

In the meantime, add your observers after you set up the graph.

Comment: I didn't think to wade through the CorePlot source.  But, yes, it's there under the `updateNotifications` method.  I also noticed that `dealloc` also already calls `removeObserver`.  I see there are two methods that call it: `setHostedGraph`, and `setCollapsesLayers`.  I think I will post it as a bug, because I wonder how one could reliably subclass `CPTGraphHostingView` without having to regularly re-`addObserver` every time the graph structure is modified.

Answer (score 0):

self is probably being reassigned after you subscribe to the notification center. Can you move the code to

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver: self  selector:@selector(recordUpdated) name:@"recordUpdated" object:nil];
}
```

or maybe to -**viewDidLoad** ?

Comment: I added some additional code and a note.  These are not UIViews, so they aren't awaken from Nibs.

Comment: @Adam what does -prepareGraph do?

Comment: The Core Plot hosting view is a subclass of UIView. Therefore, your subclass is, too.

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin, prepare graph just does CorePlot things like defining the graph axes and setting up the plot space.

Comment: @EricSkroch, You're probably right, but it still doesn't answer -why- it fails in the manner it does.  I can already make it work doing something different, and I could move it into `viewDidLoad` (assuming it is called), but it -should- work inside `init`.

Comment: @Adam Its quite possible prepareGraph is doing something to self. Its always safe to register for notifications outside of init.

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin `prepareGraph` is a method I wrote.  Eric did find the cause in the super class, now I need to find a reliable way around it.